# Problems running MERN tests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I'm considering using the MERN framework for a new project and so far I'm not encouraged by what I'm seeing.  I've followed the directions for setting up the project via `mern-cli` and the project does get created and does run correctly but when I execute...

`npm run test`

I get...

```
> mern-starter@2.0.0 test /Users/acooley/workspace/node_datacenter
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8080 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-test node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony-proxies node_modules/.bin/ava

/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/bin/node: bad option: --harmony-proxies
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------| File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------| All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|


npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test" npm ERR! node v7.1.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! mern-starter@2.0.0 test: `cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8080 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-test node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony-proxies node_modules/.bin/ava` npm ERR! Exit status 9 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the mern-starter@2.0.0 test script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8080 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-test node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony-proxies node_modules/.bin/ava'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mern-starter package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8080 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-test node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony-proxies node_modules/.bin/ava npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!    npm bugs mern-starter npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mern-starter npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR!     /Users/acooley/workspace/node_datacenter/npm-debug.log
```

Has anybody else run into this?  I really want to use this framework, but not having functional TDD is a show stopper.

Answer (score 1):

Running the test cases for MERN 2.0 (currently the most recent version) fails with node v6+. Here's what I did to get the tests working on OS X:

```
$ brew remove node
$ brew install nvm
$ nvm install 5
$ nvm alias default 5
$ npm install -g mern-cli
$ mern init your_new_app
$ cd your_new_app
$ npm install
$ npm run test
```

Answer (score 1):

found on another post/site : update your `test` script in your package.js, and change `--harmony-proxies` to `--harmony`.  ( reference n-makarov commented on Feb 12 : https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/issues/366 )